# inverse of matrix n by n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So here is a question that has crossed my mind and never left it:

suppose we have a matrix A($n \times n$) and matrix $B(n \times m$), since $(A^{-1})\cdot (B^{-1})$ is equivalent to saying $(A\cdot B)^{-1}$ can I then say that $(A-B)^{-1}$ is also equivalent to $A^{-1} -B^{-1}$?

Q2)
if we have matrices $A_1 A_2 A_3 \ldots A_n$ and suppose that we are to take the inverse of their product will the results be equivalent to taking the inverse of the individual matrices before the multiplication? I mean does the order change after the taking the inverse of them  i.e. if $(A_1\cdot A_2\cdot \ldots \cdot A_n)^{-1}$ will that be equivalent to $A_1^{-1}\cdot A_2^{-1}\cdot \ldots \cdot A_n^{-1}$ given that the matrix multiplication is defined?
Thank you for  your help :)

Comment: I edited your post to take advantage of math typesetting, but it was unclear what you meant by (A-B), were we multiplying $B$ by $-1$, or subtracting $B$ from $A$?

Comment: @pjs36 Thank you mate! yea subtracting B from A :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if $B$ is an $n \times m$ matrix with $n \not= m$ (it's not square) then $B^{-1}$ will not exist. Only square matrices can have (two-sided) inverses.

Second, in general $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$ (the order is reversed). Some people refer to this as the "socks-shoes" principle. Think of getting dressed. First, you put on your socks then your shoes. To undo this, first you takes off your shoes and then off with your socks (the order of operation is reversed).

If you have a list of things (where all of the individual things have inverses), the inverse of their composition will be the individual things inverted and written down in reverse order.

So $(A_1A_2\cdots A_n)^{-1} = A_n^{-1}A_{n-1}^{-1}\cdots A_1^{-1}$.

As for your other question (assuming the edit is accurate), it is usually not the case that $(A-B)^{-1}=A^{-1}-B^{-1}$. Think of what this would be in terms of $1 \times 1$ matrices (i.e. real numbers): $$\frac{1}{A-B} = \frac{1}{A}-\frac{1}{B}$$
This usually does not hold.

Comment: And any two of $A$, $B$, and $A-B$ could have inverses without the third having one.

Comment: Also, true. For example: $A=I$, $B=I$, $A-B=0$ OR $A=I$, $B=0$, $A-B=I$ OR $A=0$, $B=I$, $A-B=-I$. :)